# insert full path of folder which located locally to json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, url

this is my json file, i want to insert to 'url' the following path:
C:\Users\yw1kew\AppData\Local\dmv\dmv.data\cameraApp 
but I want it to be locally to any computer. then i need to start write the path from appdata some way i think
how should I do that ?

```
{
  "version": "0.3.4.0",
  "url": "",
    "productSources": {
        "ps": ""
    }
}
```

Thanks to answers!!!

Comment: By typing it perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $scope.data=  {
      "version": "0.3.4.0",
      "url": "",
        "productSources": {
            "ps": ""
        }
           }
//updating the url  value
           $scope.data.url="C:\Users\yw1kew\AppData\Local\dmv\dmv.data\cameraApp";

          })
```

Comment: i correct my question, i want it to be locally to any computer. then i need to start write the path from appdata some way i think

Comment: you want to store a file locally

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the answer in javascript which is implicitly on your tags. Here is how you do it using javascript

```
var jsonFile = `{
  "version": "0.3.4.0",
  "url": "",
    "productSources": {
        "ps": ""
    }
}`;
var url = "C:\\Users\\yw1kew\\AppData\\Local\\dmv\\dmv.data\\cameraApp";
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonFile);
jsonObject.url = url;
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
```

Where `jsonString` is the final string with the path in it.

Comment: i correct my question, i want it to be locally to any computer. then i need to start write the path from appdata some way i think